# Can we remove notes layer on Openstreetmap?

Tags: openstreetmap, layers

Have a look at the following link :

[A piece of OSM map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/32.65492/51.66932)

You can see many violet points which is added by people, I want to know if I can load only the road maps without these  violet points ( these points and related icons (such as shoes ,bicycle, climbing, ...) representing restaurants,banks,shops, ... and I do not need them. They make my map busy).

And maybe good to say that I dislike the style of humanitarian/transport/cycle map. Standard style is the best for my work.

Comment: These are POIs, not notes. [OSM notes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Notes) is a completely different feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because Openstreetmap provides only tiles to you and not the features itself. So an image is rendered on the OSM server and provided to you.

If you don't want certain features to be displayed you can either search for a map that is styled in a way you like it. The [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers) provides a nice collection of tiled maps based on OSM data.

Another way is to create a map yourself. [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) provides this service for example.